# How to troubleshoot launching the wrong version of a Vue project on a local development server after changing the port number?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

As mentioned in the title, I don’t even know what keywords to use to search on Google. Here’s the context:

In summary, I developed a project with two versions, Vue2 and Vue3, which are stored in separate folders.Here’s the folder structure:

```bash
├── project # project name
│   ├── vue2 # Vue 2 version that has been developed. Runs on localhost:8080 with Webpack.
│   ├── vue3 # Vue 3 version that is currently being developed. Runs on localhost:8001 with Vite.
```

The Vue2 version has been completed and deployed, while the Vue3 version is still in development and utilizes a different tech stack.

While running the Vue3 version locally, I initially encountered no issues. However, after changing the port to 8080 and running it again, the browser displayed the Vue2 version. Regardless of what port I subsequently used, the Vue2 version persisted.This prevented me from previewing the Vue3 version locally, but the version would correctly display after building.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

I have attempted the following steps to resolve the issue: changing the port number, using a browser's private browsing mode, trying different browsers, clearing the project cache, clearing the browser cache, deleting the .lock file and reinstalling dependencies. Despite these attempts, I am still unable to run the Vue3 version of the project locally.